# Enum variable default value?

Tags: c++, variables, enums, default-value

The question is simple:

```
#include <iostream>

enum SomeEnum {  
    EValue1 = 1,  
    EValue2 = 4
};

int main() {
    SomeEnum enummy;
    std::cout << (int)enummy;
}
```

What will be the output?

Note: This is *not* an interview, this is code inherited by me from previous developers. Streaming operator here is just for example, actual inherited code doesn't have it.

Comment: No, I'm just looking at the inherited code base with such code, unfortunately...

Comment: Looking at answer(-s), I understand that it's just another confirmation of good old rule: "Never write prototypes". But this is what most of developers have to deal with - somebody's other prototypes...

Comment: @phresnel: When I wrote 'The question is simple' I mean that the _question_ is simple, i.e. easy to ask, and of course not that answer is simple.

Comment: You will get a random number. (Or really what happens to be on the stack at that moment.) But some compilers will set enummy to 0.

Comment: @Haspemulator: "Never write prototypes"?? Where did you find *that* rule? Always write prototypes. Besides, where is the prototype in this question?

Comment: @David Hammen: It was somewhere in the interwebs, don't remember the source. But the rationale behind that reason was the following: each prototype tends to become a production software, but usually they're not of best quality. So 'Never write prototypes' here means 'Always write code like it is production'.
For my particular question, prototype is the code I received from previous developers (you know, like "take this prototype and make production code from it"), which have stuff like that uninitialized enum variable.

Comment: Oh, that kind of prototype. I thought you were hearkening back to K&R-style. Nonetheless, my questioning of the comment "Never write prototypes" stands. It is a very valuable tool in real engineering. A software prototype is no more real than is a quarter-scale, plastic mockup of a car. The problem with software prototypes is that some think that the prototype is close to the final product. It is a prototype for the final product; the prototype itself needs to be thrown out. But don't throw out the concept of prototyping. It is far too valuable when used correctly.

Comment: I use prototypes all the time. For example, I often compile a one-line source file whose sole content is `#include "/dev/tty"`. Special care is needed to feed the compilation, but the file is not going to be reused.

Comment: @QuentinUK: You'll get an *arbitrary* number; "random" means something very specific. But in fact, I believe the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The program has [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The value of enummy is indeterminate. Conceptually there is no difference between your code and the following code:

```
int main() {
   int i;          //indeterminate value
   std::cout << i; //undefined behavior
};
```

If you had defined your variable at namespace scope, it would be value initialized to 0.

```
enum SomeEnum {  
    EValue1 = 1,  
    EValue2 = 4,  
};
SomeEnum e; // e is 0
int i;      // i is 0

int main()
{
    cout << e << " " << i; //prints 0 0 
}
```

Don't be surprised that `e` can have values different from any of `SomeEnum`'s enumerator values. Each enumeration type has an underlying integral type(such as `int`, `short`, or `long`) and the set of possible values of an object of that enumeration type is the set of values that the underlying integral type has. Enum is just a way to conveniently name some of the values and create a new type, but you don't restrict the values of your enumeration by the set of the enumerators' values.

***Update:*** Some quotes backing me:

> To zero-initialize an object of type T means:
>       — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0
>   (zero) converted to T;

Note that enumerations are scalar types.

> To value-initialize an object of type T means: 
>  — if T is a class type
>   blah blah 
>  — if T is a non-union class
>   type blah blah 
>   — if T is an array type, then blah blah —
>   otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

So, we get into otherwise part. And namespace-scope objects are value-initialized

Comment: Thanks for info. Could you please point to specific paragraph in the C++ standard?

Comment: @Implicit in the last part of the answer is the fact that unless the user defines their own streaming operator for the enumeration, the default streaming for integral types is used after a conversion.  So, even if `e` is set to `EValue1`, "1" will be printed and not "EValue1".  You are allowed to create your own `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, SomeEnum)` function though.

Comment: @Haspemulator: Armen's explanation implicitly or explicitly covers many things: reading from uninitialised variables, initialisation of statics, implicit Standard conversion of enumerations to integral values....  IMHO, it's not reasonable to expect him to identify the relevant parts of the Standard for all of these, and you need to spend some time reading about the basics of C++.

Comment: @Tony: yes, I understand. I've written this comment when Armen's answer consisted from just one sentence. :)

Comment: @Haspemulator: I suspect Amen's original answer was "The program has Undefined Behavior." That should have been enough, shouldn't it? Don't invoke undefined behavior. If you do invoke undefined behavior, don't ask what the response will be. The response to undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @David Hammen: Yes, you're right, that was the original answer. But as far as I know, in C++ standard all the cases of undefined behavior are explicitly defined. I wanted only to read something official about it, and I thought that it would make the answer a little bit better (though it is good in its current state).

Comment: @Haspemulator: Oh, no, it's not true that all cases of UB are explicitly mentioned. There is a special clause that says that all behavior that isn't explicitly defined is implicitly undefined! And my original answer was one sentence longer :)

Comment: @Armen: thanks for clarification, I was not aware of that clause (actually, I have to admit that I've not read C++ standard as whole, only partially). I just saw that _some_ cases of UB are specially mentioned there, and have made a false assumption spreading this fact to all such cases.

Comment: In fact, this particular case is explicitly mentioned: ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) section 4.1, Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, states that "if the object is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior."

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: +1 for _Enum is just a way to conveniently name some of the values and create a new type, but you don't restrict the values of your enumeration by the set of the enumerators' values._

Comment: I think that the storage class also matters for the default value. As in your case the variables e and i are both global and will be stored in uninitialized part of data segment (bss) and hence the variable has 0 value.