# What are global strongly-typed enums initialized to by default in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, initialization

I'm trying to determine the default value to which global strongly-type enums are initialized. The following code of course does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class A{a=10, b=20};

// Global strongly-typed enum, uninitialized
A k;

int main() {
    if(k==A::a)
        cout<<"Equal to a"<<endl;
    else if(k==A::b)
        cout<<"Equal to b"<<endl;
    else if(k==0)
        cout<<"Equal to zero"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What is 'k' initialized to?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp No, that's not a duplicate. The one you linked to is asking about a function-scope unscoped enumeration. This one is about a namespace-scope scoped enumeration. *Very* different things.

Comment: it IS a duplicate. You can find the answer for your question in the answer for the duplicate linked above

Comment: @glezmen I still don't think so - that other question does not cover scoped enumerations. Yes, the answer is the same, but that doesn't make it a duplicate question.

Comment: @Angew "f you had defined your variable at namespace scope, it would be value initialized to 0." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842799/c-enum-variable-default-value

Comment: @glezmen A "scoped enumeration" is `enum class`, and "unscoped enumeration" is just `enum`. The linked question does not deal with scoped enumerations (`enum class` types) at all.

Answer (score 10):

`k` has static storage duration and static objects are zero initialized, we can see this by going to the [draft C++ standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) section `3.6.2` *Initialization of non-local variables* paragraph *2*:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage
>   duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other
>   initialization takes place. [...]

for scalar types that means initialization to zero, which is covered section `8.5` paragraph *6* which says:

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:

and includes the following bullet:

> if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value
>   obtained by converting the integer literal 0 (zero) to T;105

we know an enum is a scalar type from section `3.9` *Types* paragraph *9* which says:

> Arithmetic types (3.9.1), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to
>   member types (3.9.2), std::nullptr_- t, and cv-qualified versions of
>   these types (3.9.3) are collectively called scalar types.[...]

`zero` is a valid value since the underlying type can contain its value and section `7.2` *Enumeration declarations* paragraph *8* says that an enumeration can take a value not defined by its enumerators:

> [...]It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not
>   defined by any of its enumerators.[...]

Answer (score 3):

It is zero initialized. Take into account that the underlaying type of this enumeration is `int` (by default) and 0 is a valid enumerator though it is not explicitly used in any enumerator definition of the enumeration..

Only you have to write

```
else if( k == static_cast<A>( 0 ) )
    cout<<"Equal to zero"<<endl;
```

If you would use C# then zero can be implicitly converted to an enumeration of any type.:)