# Default value of enum declared in class

Tags: c++, enums, undefined, undefined-behavior

I have a class whose member is an enum declared inside this class:

```
#include<iostream>

class test
{
public:
    enum TYPE{MAN, WOMAN};

    TYPE type;
};


int main()
{
    test x;
    if(x.type == test::MAN) std::cout<<"MAN"<<std::endl;
    if(x.type == test::WOMAN) std::cout<<"WOMAN"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"ok"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842799/c-enum-variable-default-value) that if an enum is declared at namespace scope, it has a default value 0 and when it's declared locally, it doesn't have any default values, which leads to undefined behavior.

My question is: what if I have an enum which belongs to a class? Is it undefined behavior as well?

I tested the above code and *x.type* is neither *MAN* nor *WOMAN*. However, I've done it for only one compiler and one operating system. I'm interested in a more general answer. I haven't found any information regarding this issue anywhere else.

Edit1: Can referring to this indeterminate value cause segmentation fault?

Edit2: I know this is not a well designed class- it's not mine and I'm trying to debug it. So telling me that I can default-initialize object doesn't solve my problem. Please, treat it as a theoretical question.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with enums. `struct X { int n; };` would have the exact same problem.

Comment: You should either give your `type` member a brace-or-equal initializer, or give your `test` class a default constructor with initializes `type` to a default value

Comment: It's not about the enum, it's about reading an uninitialized variable. UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of the first name in an `enum` is 0, regardless of the scope of the `enum`.

There is no guaranteed default value of an automatic local variable like `test x;` in `main` here. It has an **indeterminate value**. And it's Undefined Behavior to use that value.

You can ¹default-initialize it like this:

```
test x{};
```

---

<sup>¹ A subtle point is that at top level this gives a “value-initialization”.</sup>

Comment: OP asks about default value of a enum variable if it's not initialized.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the default value of the `TYPE type` object

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Can refering to this indeterminate value cause segmentation fault?

Comment: @user2738748: In theory yes, with UB anything can happen. Not the least because a compiler can see formal UB as a *carte blanche* to do all kinds of unexpected, surprising optimizations. But also because an architecture can have *trap representations* for integer values, and/or use extra trap bits to catch the use of uninitialized (indeterminate) values.

Answer (score 2):

If your object don't have any constructors, then it depends on where you create your object. If it's created globally, then all variables are zero-initialized. If not, they are not initialized properly and reading from them results in UB.

You can force zero-initialization of a non-global variable with `test x{};` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

First: "Testing" for undefined behavior is almost never going to give you the right answer.

This is [undefined behavior](http://[1]:%20http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you are reading from an uninitialized variable with automatic storage duration. Such a variable has an **indeterminate value** and must not be read from. Every non-static function scope variable has automatic storage duration.

I think you are confusing the **definition** of the enum type (which happens inside the class definition) with the **declaration** of a variable of this type (at function scope). In your example `x` is a variable with automatic storage duration no matter where the type `TYPE` has been defined.