# No default constructor is available for the specified class, structure, or union

Tags: c++, constructor

Trying to create a class. When i put `{` after constructor, `vs2015` shows me an error

> No default constructor is available for the specified class, structure, or union.

Theres a code snippets:

**NumberExpression.h:**

```
class NumberExpression : Expression {
private:
    Token m_token;
public:
    NumberExpression(Token tok);
    double evaluate();
};
```

**NumberExpression.cpp:**

```
NumberExpression::NumberExpression(Token tok) {
    m_token = tok;
}
```

**Token.h:**

```
class Token {
public:
    enum TYPE { NUM, ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, EoF };
private:
    char* m_text;
    TYPE m_type;
public:
    Token(TYPE type, char* text);

    TYPE getType() const { return m_type; }
    char* getText() const { return m_text; }
};
```

I know that i can just create an Empty constructor, but why this error happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asked this:

> I know that i can just create an Empty constructor, but why this error happens?

Your class `NumberExpression` has a constructor that takes a `Token` object.

In this class's constructor body you are using `Token's` copy assignment operator. `m_token = tok;` that is defined by the compiler by default.

In your class `Token` the constructor that you declared & defined is expecting 2 parameters in its parameter list. Yet when you try to use the copy assignment operator this is why the compiler is giving you that error. You are trying to assign a copy of a `Token` object and save(store) it to a member of `NumberExpression`. Since you declared a `constructor` for `Token` that takes two parameters the compiler will not use the default `ctor` or `copy ctor` because you have not supplied one after declaring a `user defined constructor` and it can not find the declaration or definition of a default `ctor`.

---

There are three ways to fix this:

1. Provide a Default or empty constructor in the header simply as:

   - `Token() = default;`
   - `Token();`
   - `Token() {}`
2. Use `NumberExpression's` class member initializer list as others have stated:

   - `NumberExpression::NumberExpression( Token token ) : m_token( token ) {...}`
3. Or use both in combination.

Also since you are passing a single object into `NumberExpression's` constructor
if you want to prevent automatic implicit conversion or casting by the compiler and want to make it strict you can use the `explicit` keyword on the Constructor's declaration:

```
class NumberExpression : public Expression {
private: 
    Token m_token;
public:
    explicit NumberExpression( Token token ) : m_token( token ) {}
    double evaluate();
};
```

To set the default initialization list for the token class:

```
class Token {
public:
    enum Type {
        INVALID = -1,
        NUM,
        ADD,
        SUB,
        MUL,
        DIV,
        EOF
    };
private:
    char* m_text;
    Type m_type;
public:
    Token(Type type, char* text) : m_type(INVALID), m_text(nullptr) {}

    Type getType() const { return m_type; }
    char* getText() const { return m_text; }
};
```

Comment: What is the default initialization value of enum?

Comment: @Davar The OP can add another enum value before all others such as `enum { INVALID = -1, all others, };` Then set that in the initializer list.

Comment: That's true, but I was more interested in the question if the enums are default constructible and what is their behavior like.

Comment: @Dava that's actually a good question; not sure if they are default constructible or not (don't remember), but I do believe that they are of an integer type...

Comment: @Francio Cigler I tested it - they seem to be be default AND trivially AND nothrow constructible (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible), but without namespace scope they really have undefined behavior (they are of value 0 in namespace).
There is also similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842799/enum-variable-default-value

Comment: @Davar Yeah I think I just read that question too.

Answer (score 3):

```
NumberExpression::NumberExpression(Token tok) {
    m_token = tok;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
NumberExpression::NumberExpression(Token tok) : m_token() {
    m_token = tok;
}
```

Since `Token` does not have a default constructor, the compiler complains. And rightly so.

Change that to use a valid constructor of `Token`.

```
NumberExpression::NumberExpression(Token tok) : m_token(tok) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `m_token` via [member intializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation) directly.

> For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

e.g.

```
NumberExpression::NumberExpression(Token tok) : m_token(tok) {
}
```

In your implementation, `m_token` will be default initialized at first, then assigned in the body of the constructor of `NumberExpression`. But `Token` doesn't have a default constructor.